# Use Jenkins-agent as Azure container instance

Tags: azure, jenkins, command-line-interface, azure-container-instances

I'm following the steps in this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/azure-container-instances-as-jenkins-build-agent?source=recommendations). I'm having trouble executing this CLI command:

```
az container create \
  --name docks \
  --resource-group MyResourceGroup \
  --ip-address Public \
  --image jenkins/inbound-agent:latest \
  --os-type linux \
  --ports 80 \
  --command-line "jenkins-agent -url http://jenkinsServer:8080 secret agentName"
```

It gives the following output:

```
{
"containers": [
    {
      "command": [
        "jenkins-agent",
        "-url",
        "http://jenkinsServer:8080",
        "secret",
        "agentName"
      ],
      "environmentVariables": [],
      "image": "jenkins/inbound-agent:latest",
      "instanceView": {
        "currentState": {
          "detailStatus": "CrashLoopBackOff: Back-off restarting failed",
          "exitCode": null,
          "finishTime": null,
          "startTime": null,
          "state": "Waiting"
        },
        "events": [
          {
            "count": 1,
            "firstTimestamp": "2022-09-07T16:57:57+00:00",
            "lastTimestamp": "2022-09-07T16:57:57+00:00",
            "message": "pulling image \"jenkins/inbound-agent@sha256:f495769bfc767bc77f6c2f8268a734dbac98249449f139f95fc434eb26c6489a\"",
            "name": "Pulling",
            "type": "Normal"
          },
          {
            "count": 1,
            "firstTimestamp": "2022-09-07T16:59:00+00:00",
            "lastTimestamp": "2022-09-07T16:59:00+00:00",
            "message": "Successfully pulled image \"jenkins/inbound-agent@sha256:f495769bfc767bc77f6c2f8268a734dbac98249449f139f95fc434eb26c6489a\"",
            "name": "Pulled",
            "type": "Normal"
          },
          {
            "count": 2,
            "firstTimestamp": "2022-09-07T16:59:57+00:00",
            "lastTimestamp": "2022-09-07T17:00:18+00:00",
            "message": "Started container",
            "name": "Started",
            "type": "Normal"
          },
          {
            "count": 1,
            "firstTimestamp": "2022-09-07T17:00:08+00:00",
            "lastTimestamp": "2022-09-07T17:00:08+00:00",
            "message": "Killing container with id XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.",
            "name": "Killing",
            "type": "Normal"
          }
        ],
        "previousState": {
          "detailStatus": "Error",
          "exitCode": 255,
          "finishTime": "2022-09-07T17:00:29.169000+00:00",
          "startTime": "2022-09-07T17:00:18.785000+00:00",
          "state": "Terminated"
        },
        "restartCount": 1
      },
      "livenessProbe": null,
      "name": "docks",
      "ports": [
        {
          "port": 80,
          "protocol": "TCP"
        }
      ],
      "readinessProbe": null,
      "resources": {
        "limits": null,
        "requests": {
          "cpu": 1.0,
          "gpu": null,
          "memoryInGb": 1.5
        }
      },
      "volumeMounts": null
    }
  ],
  "diagnostics": null,
  "dnsConfig": null,
  "encryptionProperties": null,
  "id": "/subscriptions/azureSub/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/docks",
  "identity": null,
  "imageRegistryCredentials": null,
  "initContainers": [],
  "instanceView": {
    "events": [],
    "state": "Running"
  },
  "ipAddress": {
    "dnsNameLabel": null,
    "fqdn": null,
    "ip": "XX.XXX.XXX.XX",
    "ports": [
      {
        "port": 80,
        "protocol": "TCP"
      }
    ],
    "type": "Public"
  },
  "location": "westeurope",
  "name": "docks",
  "osType": "Linux",
  "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
  "resourceGroup": "MyResourceGroup",
  "restartPolicy": "Always",
  "sku": "Standard",
  "subnetIds": null,
  "tags": {},
  "type": "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups",
  "volumes": null,
  "zones": null
}
```

As you see it gives a 255 Error, however I didn't find anything related to it yet.

I also tried to change the `--command-line` to:

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://jenkinsServer:8080 secret agentName
```

But the same output happens.
This creates the Container, but it keeps restarting indefinitely (starts and fails).

The Jenkins server is in a Linux VM made following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/configure-on-linux-vm)

How can I make a Jenkins agent from the VM be run in a docker container image using Azure?

Answer (score 1):

***When I tried to reproduce the issue, noted that we have different ways to get*** **CrashLoopBackOff error.**

**1). ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES SETUP**

- CrashLoopBackOff will occur when the environment variables are set incorrectly.
- please check the **ENV_PATH** set to be correct or not
  type `ENV` in *Azure Cli* or *PowerShell*

[image]

**2). INSTALLING THE CORRECT VERSION OF S/W**

- can you please check which java version you have installed
- if it is JDK-8, please update it to 11.0.16.1, it will work

  ```
    apt-get update -y 
    apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk
  ```

[image]

after installing java I have followed the steps [Ms-Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/azure-container-instances-as-jenkins-build-agent?source=recommendations) and created the container instance successfully.

```
az container create \
  --name docks \
  --resource-group jenkins-get-started-rgz \
  --ip-address Public \
  --image jenkins/inbound-agent:latest \
  --os-type linux \
  --ports 80 \
  --command-line "jenkins-agent -url http://jenkinsServer:8080 JENKINS_SECRET AGENT_NAME"
```

[image]
[image]

**NOTE:**

1. *if the **EXIT CODE** is "**0**" means we have created the container instance **successfully***
2. *if the **EXIT CODE** is in between "**1-255**" it corresponds to **error***.